# error in redirecting onmouseover to other elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I want that the moment I move my mouse over the svg, the text will shift to the right, making it visible; however it is not working. What would be the problem?

HTML:

```
<div class="exitBox">               
            <span class="exitButton"><?php include "SVGs/sair.svg"; ?></span>
            <span class="exit"><a href="#" id="exitA">SAIR</a></span>               
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.exitBox{
            display: inline;
            position: fixed;
            top: 20px;
            left: 40px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .exitButton svg{
            width: 20px;
            color: black;
        }

        #exitA{
            display: inline-block;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: black;
            font-size: 30px;
            letter-spacing: 2px;
            font-family: Teko;
            transform: translateX(-100px);
        }
```

SCRIPT JS:

```
var exit = document.getElementById("exitA");
        var exitB = document.getElementsByClassName("exitButton");
        
        exitB.onmouseover = function exit(){
            exit.style.transform = "translateX(100px)";  
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You use the same name for the function and the exit element.
2. You are moving it to 100px from -100px, which means 200px, this leads the text to go out of the screen

```js
var exitB = document.getElementsByClassName("exitButton")[0];

exitB.onmouseenter = function exit(){
      var exitA = document.getElementById("exitA");
      exitA.style.transform = "translateX(0)";  
}
```

```css
.exitBox{
    display: inline;
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    left: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.exitButton svg{
    width: 20px;
    color: black;
}

#exitA{
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-size: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-family: Teko;
    transform: translateX(-100px);
}
```

```html
<div class="exitBox">               
    <span class="exitButton"><div>hover</div></span>
    <span class="exit"><a href="#" id="exitA">SAIR</a></span>               
</div>
```